# select is not valid at this position in SQLworkbench

Tags: mysql, sql

When I execute following sql, the error returned

`select is not valid at this position for this server version , expecting for, lock, table,values, with, '('`

My sql like following.

```
select 
id
,COALESCE(count(*) FILTER (WHERE snapshot_day in ('2021-04-19')), 0) AS "2021-04-19"
,COALESCE(count(*) FILTER (WHERE snapshot_day in ('2021-04-20')), 0) AS "2021-04-20"
,COALESCE(count(*) FILTER (WHERE snapshot_day in ('2021-04-21')), 0) AS "2021-04-21"
from table
where type in ('Daily')
group by 1
```

I checked my query but I couldn't find any mistakes..

Where is the problems?

If someone has opinion,please let me know

Thanks

Comment: `FILTER` is ProstgreSQL (and, maybe, some another DBMS) feature, and it is not applicable in MySQL.

Comment: @Akina: `filter` is actually part of the SQL standard, not PostgreSQL specific. But indeed, support is not widespread. To my knowledge only Postgres, HSQLDB and SQLite support it

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, there is no `FILTER` in mysql but you can still achieve the same effect with something like this:

```
select 
id
,coalesce(sum(case when snapshot_day in ('2021-04-19') then 1 else 0 end), 0) AS "2021-04-19"
,coalesce(sum(case when snapshot_day in ('2021-04-20') then 1 else 0 end), 0) AS "2021-04-20"
,coalesce(sum(case when snapshot_day in ('2021-04-21') then 1 else 0 end), 0) AS "2021-04-21"
from table
where type in ('Daily')
group by 1
```